# What is the premium such that it is equal to the $90^{th}$ percentile of the distribution of total claims?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, approximation

A company has a one-year group life policy that divides its employees into two classes as follows:

Class,    Probability of Death,    Benefit,        Number in Class,

A,              0.01,          $20000,            1000

B, 0.03, $10000, 500

The insurance company wants to collect a premium that equals the $90^{th}$ percentile of the distribution of total claims. Calculate this premium.

I don't know how to approach it. I was thinking of using an approximation by separating each class into a different distribution with 1000/500 samples each but I don't know what kind of distributions they would create and what the parameters would be?

Comment: One can expect about 10 Class A claims and about 15 Class B claims. Then what is the expected distribution of claims?

Comment: so you would expect about $10 \times 20000 + 15 \times 10000 = 350 000$ to be the amount claimed but what does this say about the distribution? What about the variance?

Comment: maybe binomial?

Comment: The _distribution_ of payouts would have about 10 at \$20,000 and about 15 at $10,000; that's a list of about 25 numbers. Hardly normal, I'd say.

Comment: oh so it could be 2 uniform distributions then? that would make up a joint one

Comment: but how is that the distribution. Isn't that the expected result. I'm getting confused about this concept of the $90^{th}$ percentile

Comment: I was not answering the question directly. Just trying to give you a general idea what the distribution of payouts must look like. Of course, it is conceivable that all deaths are in Class A or all in Class B, but hardly likely. Look at the def'n of 90th percentile. It takes a little consideration when there lots of repeated values. For example, f you have data 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,,2,2,2,2,2,2, then the 90th percentile is 2 (and so is the 75th). -- Sorry, got to leave the screen now for several hours.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you were intended to use a normal approximation

- the expected number of claims in the the first class is $0.01 \times 1000 =10$ with variance  $0.01 \times 0.99 \times 1000 = 9.9$; so the expected value of claims is $10 \times 20000 = 200000$ with variance $9.9 \times 20000^2 = 3960000000$
- the expected number of claims in the the first class is $0.03 \times 500 =15$ with variance  $0.03 \times 0.97 \times 1000 = 14.55$; so the expected value of claims is $15 \times 10000 = 150000$ with variance $14.55 \times 10000^2 = 1455000000$
- so overall the expected value of claims is $200000+150000=350000$ with variance $3960000000+1455000000 = 5415000000$
- the $90$th percentile of a standard normal distribution is about $1.281552$ and so for this case the $90$th percentile of claims is about $350000+ 1.281552 \times \sqrt{5415000000} \approx 444305$
- actual claims are in multiples of $10000$ so you might consider round this up to $450000$

In this case a more precise calculation might be possible.  Using R

```
claims   <- outer((0:1000)*20000, (0:500)*10000, "+")  
probs    <- outer(dbinom(0:1000,1000,0.01), dbinom(0:500,500,0.03), "*")
cumprobs <- cumsum(probs[order(claims)])
claims[order(claims)][min(which(cumprobs >= 0.9))]
# 450000
```

Looking that the probabilities of the actual total claims being no more than $444305$ or $440000$ or $450000$ would give

```
sum(probs[claims <= 444305]) 
# 0.89784
sum(probs[claims <= 440000]) 
# 0.89784
sum(probs[claims <= 450000]) 
# 0.9181994
```

so the normal approximation seems to produce a reasonable result here